# Compling C# Expression with values

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have combined two expression with Expression.And. How can I compile this new expression with actual values?

```
var expr1 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "param1"), Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "param2"));
var expr2 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "param3"), Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "param4"));
var finalExpression = Expression.And(expr1, expr2);
```

I'm trying to get to work somoething like this after substiting the parameters with values

```
bool returnBool =  Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(finalExpression).Compile()();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile it to a lambda with the same parameters:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int, int, bool>>(
    finalExpression, param1, ...).Compile();
lambda(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Note that you need to pass the same `Expression.Parameter()` instances used in the expression to `Lambda()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the parameters with constants, you can do that using an `ExpressionVisitor`, substituting any instances of the params with `Expression.Constant`. Then you can compile the lambda to a type *without* the parameters. Alternatively, you can build a lambda that *involves* the other lambda - not at a PC, but it is `Expression.Invoke` or `Expression.Call` - basically, it acts like a sub-call.

Comment: Thank you Marc Gravell. I'm accepting @SLaks answer, But I would probably end up using ExpressionVisitor later for a better solution

Comment: @ManojSreekumar no problem; and I looked it up - it is `Expression.Invoke`. So `var newBody = Expression.Lambda(oldLambda, Expression.Constant(123), Expression.Constant("abc"));` etc